# Messaging.SendEmailResult not working after exception thrown

Tags: apex

I have this code:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static list<quotelineitem> insertForecastQuote(Id oppId, string productsData,string tier, string contractType){
    try {
        //code block
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses('myemailaddress');
        mail.setSubject('subject');
        mail.setHtmlBody('body');
        try{
            Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{mail});
        }catch(Exception e){}
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage() + '\n' + e.getStackTraceString());
    }   
}
```

When I get an exception, for some reason the email isn't sent.
However, when I just try to execute the block that sends the email it does work.

What can be the reason?

Comment: A try/catch inside of a catch strikes me as a bad idea (and `catch(Exception e)`, the "pokemon catch" is also generally poor practice, though may be appropriate for code called from a lightning/aura component). That aside, is the inner `catch(Exception e){}` really like that in your code, with an empty body? If so, was that intentional?

Answer (score 2):

Unhandled errors always roll back the entire transaction, including any DML, email sends, jobs enqueued, etc.

Other than that, some notes:

- You should never under any circumstances use an empty `catch` block.
- Generally, if you are catching generic `Exception`, it indicates you do not know what specific type to trap. This uncertainty about application behavior is a red flag. Try isolating your `catch` blocks to only the types which can be thrown.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Larson, Why this is considered "uncaught exception"? I have a catch that handles it, and inside this catch I want to a. send an email and b. throw an exception to the JavaScript (which is also handled there)

Comment: You `throw` an Exception which never caught.

Answer (score 2):

You can't both send an email *and* indicate an error to the client, at least not directly. This is because any uncaught exception will roll back pretty much everything about a transaction, including records created, modified, deleted, undeleted, merged, and/or converted, as well as emails, schedulable, queueable, and batchable jobs, as well as future methods. The only two things not rolled back are callouts (because they've already been processed externally) and Immediately Published Platform Events.

If you want to send an email, either set up your JavaScript controller to handle the error and send the email in a separate transaction or use an Immediately Publish Platform Event to send the email asynchronously in a separate thread.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox, but why this is considered "uncaught exception"? I have a catch that handles it, and inside this catch I want to a. send an email and b. throw an exception to the JavaScript (which is also handled there)

Comment: @MichaelImas An exception that is not handled by the time Apex reaches the bottom of the stack is considered uncaught and will return a 500 error code to the client. This is what triggers the rollback; it doesn't matter that JavaScript will eventually handle it, it only matters at the moment that the method at the bottom of the stack has an unhandled exception. That's why you have to either handle it as a separate method call or use something that can't be rolled back, like a callout or Platform Event.